# How to limit traffic through hosts using Openflow in Mininet

Tags: networking, sdn, mininet, openflow

I have simulated a network using SDN, that has 3 hosts and 3 switches, with the below code using Mininet

I want to figure out how to block certain dest TCP/UDP ports while simulating traffic. And also to limit the traffic between certain hosts to a certain value based on requirement.

I have created queues using Openflow to try and limit the traffic between the queues, but for some reason the traffic doesn't get limited according to the min-rate and max-rate that I set for each queue using Openflow

I'm creating multiple switches, so every switch contains 3 queues with rates of 1GBps, 1MBps and 512kbps as shown below:

```
queuecmd = "sudo ovs-vsctl %s -- --id=@defaultqos create qos
type=linux-htb other-config:max-rate=1000000000
queues=0=@q0,1=@q1,2=@q2 -- --id=@q0 create queue
other-config:max-rate=1000000000  other-config:min-rate=1000000000 --
--id=@q1 create queue other-config:max-rate=1000000
other-config:min-rate=1000000 -- --id=@q2 create queue
other-config:max-rate=512000 other-config:min-rate=512000"
```

I'm using the following policy with the `set_queue` parameter set to the queue id I want to use:

```
S1H2 = {'switch': "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01", "name": "S1H2", "cookie": "0",
            "priority": "256", "in_port": "1", "eth_type": "0x800",
"ipv4_src": "10.0.0.1",
            "ipv4_dst": "10.0.0.2", "active": "true", "actions":
"output=2, set_queue=1"}
```

I'm trying to limit the rate to 1MBps, but despite using the queue, its giving me a rate of 1GBps. Can anybody please help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> S1H2 = {'switch': "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01", "name": "S1H2", "cookie":
> "0",
> "priority": "256", "in_port": "1", "eth_type": "0x800", "ipv4_src": "10.0.0.1",
> "ipv4_dst": "10.0.0.2", "active": "true", "actions": "output=2, set_queue=1"}

Can you try to remove the spacing between "output=2, set_queue=1" -> "output=2,set_queue=1" instead ?